# Javascript html.replace(regEx, "$0.01") doesn't work

Tags: javascript, regex, internet-explorer-9

### HTML

```
<div id="abc">
<span>$b $</span>
</div>
```

### Javascript

```
var regEx = new RegExp("\\$b \\$" , 'gi');
var html = $("#abc").html();
var app = html.replace(regEx, "$0.01");
```

### Output

This works fine if `$value` is 1.00 or greater.

For $0.01 the code results in `$b $.01`.

This issue exists in Internet Explorer 9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `$0` (in `"$0.01"`) stands for the full match in IE9, so it's replaced with `"$b $"`. Apparently you'll have to double the `$` like so :

```
var app = html.replace(regEx, '$$0.01');
```

Answer (score 1):

That would be because `$` is the javascript placeholder for regular expression capture groups. `$0` gets treated as "the entire string I tried to replace" (`$1` is "the first capture group", etc). Use `$$` in your replacement string to escape the dollar symbol and use it as an actual character.

That said, it would also make a lot of sense not to use dollar symbols in your HTLM, and to also do something like `var replaced = "$" + html.replace([placeholderRegex, actualAmount);`, so you don't encode any symbols. Making the HTML element encode the dollar symbol through a CSS rule would be even better, so your final onpage element is something like `<span class="dollar-amount">0.01</span>` with a css rule `dollar-amount:before { content: "$"; }`.

Comment: No; the escape is `$$`.

Comment: I don't think it's clear why having a $ in the HTML is not a good idea.  Since the alternative is quite a bit of boilerplate, can you explain in more detail?

Comment: not knowing why the span's content is "$b $", not specifically; but it looks like an autogenerated placeholder. Using a more conventional jade or mustache format makes the placeholder require a less special regex

Answer (score 0):

This RegExp seems to work: `[$b ]+[$]+`

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aHxL7/)